# cannot cast 'float64' to different essential type 'unsigned16' [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.8, required]

Tags: c, casting, misra, pc-lint

cannot cast 'float64' to different essential type 'unsigned16' [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.8, required]

```
double x, y;
#define MIN 2.0
uint16_t z = (uint16_t) ((x * MIN) + y);
```

How can I resolve this line throwing pc-lint note?

Answer (score 1):

Rule 10.8 states

> The value of a *composite expression* shall not be cast to a different *essential type* category or a wider *essential type*.

The Rationale provided explains why.

To resolve the violation, you need a two step approach:

```
double x, y;
#define MIN 2.0

double   w = (x * MIN) + y; /* Composite expression, in double */
uint16_t z = (uint16_t)w;   /* Explicit conversion to uint16_t */
```

Of course, you'll need to be sure that the result fits in `uint16_t`...

And yes, your compiler should optimize this.

Answer (score 1):

MISRA C has the concept of *composite expressions* which simplified means that if an arithmetic expression contains sub-expressions, it is a composite expression. (For the formal and complete definition of the term see MISRA-C:2012 8.10.3.)

The result of a composite expression can't be cast to a different essential type category, so you need to break it down in several steps:

```
double tmp = (x * MIN) + y; 
uint16_t z = (uint16_t)tmp; // OK: tmp is not a composite expression
```

The `(x * MIN) + y` part is OK because `y` is of same essential type as the composite expression `(x * MIN)`, see 10.7.

MISRA gives two different rationales for this rule:

- A lot of people supposedly don't grasp which type that is used for a calculation in C. For example some might believe that `(double)(uint16a + uint16b)` means that the addition is carried out on `double` type, which is of course wrong.
- Confusion about [implicit type promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). For example `uint16a + uint16b` will actually get carried out on a signed 32 bit type on a 32 bit or larger computer.

I'm not sure if I agree that the former rationale is a common phenomenon, but the latter surely is.